# Close the specific Window in Emacs

Tags: emacs

its really easy to create window in emacs, like C-x 2 create a window downside of the current window and C-x 3 create a window right of current window. So its easily to create a layout like:

```
    |     2      |
1   |------------|   4
    |     3      |
```

now it comes to the question, how do i fast kill the specific window (like i work in window No. 1, look something in No.2 and dont want No.3 so want fast kill it) without jumping to that window? I know that we can use C-x o to switch to that window and use C-x 0 to kill it. Are there anyway to do it like for example presse C-x k 3 to kill the window No.3?

Comment: How would you designate that emacs window?

Comment: that what i mean, i mean if given them a number like from 0 to N , with the order from left to right from top to bottom..

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way to do this in vanilla emacs, but the [ace-window](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) package provides this functionality as well as other useful window commands.

Comment: Example to delete an adjacent window:  `(delete-window (window-in-direction 'right))`.  The possible directions for this snippet are `'right`, `'left`, `'above`, `'below`.  And, of course, `delete-window` with no argument will delete the selected window.  You may also be interested in `delete-other-windows`, which has an optional argument -- see the doc-string for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use library [`frame-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el) then you can use command `delete-windows-on` to delete all windows for a given buffer. The buffer name is read with completion, so this is usually pretty quick.

Interactively:

- Without a prefix arg, deletes matching windows on all frames
- With prefix arg >= 0, deletes matching windows on only the selected (current) frame
- With prefix arg < 0,  deletes matching windows on all visible frames

You can of course use `delete-windows-on` to define your own command that always acts as does `delete-windows-on` with a positive prefix arg.  Just use `(delete-windows-on nil t)`.

(If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then `C-u C-x 0` (command `icicle-delete-window`) and command `icicle-delete-window-by-name` give you similar behavior. These are [multi-commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means you can delete multiple window with a single command invocation.)